# Как присвоить значение и получить доступ к статической переменной класса, объявленной как указатель на целое, из функции main или другого класса?

Tags: c++

Есть пример (упрощённый) кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo {
private:
    static int* intptr;
public:
    void static stuff(int* p) {
        intptr = &(*p);
        //cout << *intptr << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    int a = 33;
    Foo::stuff(&a);
}
```

При компиляции вылезает ошибка undefined reference to `Foo::intptr'. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Для статических переменных класса нужно подсказать компилятору, где сохранить все это. Самый простой способ - прямо над main написать вот такое

```
int* Foo::intptr = nullptr; // или чем там инициализировать.
```

Если стандарт (с++17) и компилятор позволяют, то можно просто вот так написать

```
    static inline int* intptr;
```

и будет тоже работать.

Comment: Супер, всё заработало (оба варианта)! 
А при доступе не из main, а из другого класса тоже будет работать?

Comment: а почему не будет. будет. Если Вы присмотритесь к ошибке, то там очевидно, что компилятору все нравится. Ругается линковщик, который не смог придумать, куда в памяти пристроить эту переменную. А указанная конструкция как раз и дает нужный эффект

Comment: Даже не знаю как вас и благодарить :-))

Comment: просто делайте добро другим.